# How to create a pie chart in php where the section is no fixed, it dynamically changes according to the user input

Tags: javascript, php

```
var data = [
         { label: "Algorithm", data: 100 },
         { label: "English", data: 100 },
         { label: "Maths", data: 100 },
         ];
```

This is the javascript for the data but i dont want the no of data to be fixed. I want it to be dynamic which depend upon the no of exam user gives.Can anyone please help me with that. Thanx in advance.

```
<div class="box-content">
                <div id="piechart" style="height:300px" ></div>
            </div>
```

I am using this to call the id="piechart"

Comment: Where does the data come from? Use AJAX perhaps? Database? ..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i dont have knowledge in php, but with JavaScript what you can do is you can create an empty array and use the `.push` method to enter new values to the array or `.replace` to replace existing data.But before that there must be a `prompt` or an empty html formfield asking the initial data for each field(s).

Lastly run the program. For a new set of data and a chart you have to reload the page since JS is a client side scripting language (therefore no databases).